# Marking specific points in mathematica plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

How can I use different figures like square, triangle, etc. to mark these points?

[image]

Comment: Post actual code in code blocks rather than images of code. Also include all code and data to reproduce the issue. In this case, the definition of `f`.

Answer (score 4):

```
f[x_] := 13/2 + (39*x)/4 - 6*x^2 + x^3

realzero = x /. Solve[f[x] == 0, x, Reals][[1]];

Show[
 Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 4}],
 ListPlot[
  List /@ (Tooltip[{#, f[#]}] & /@ {realzero, 0, 1, 3}),
  PlotStyle -> {Darker@Green, Orange, Red, Blue},
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
 AxesStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `f` and `realzero` from Bob Hanlon's answer:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_] := 13/2 + (39*x)/4 - 6*x^2 + x^3
realzero = x /. Solve[f[x] == 0, x, Reals][[1]];
```

With your desired list of colors and markers, say,

```
colors = {Darker @ Green, Orange, Red, Blue};

markers = Charting`CommonDump`GraphicsPlotMarkers[][[All, 1]];
```

construct a list of `Inset`s

```
insets = MapThread[Inset[Tooltip[Graphics@{#, First@#2}, #3], #3, Center, Scaled[.05]]&,
  {colors, markers[[;; Length @ colors]], {#, f @ #} & /@ {realzero, 0, 1, 2}}];
```

and use it as the option setting for `Epilog`:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 4}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
  AxesStyle -> Dashed, 
  ImageSize -> Large,
  Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False},
  Epilog -> insets]
```

[image]

If desired, add the option

```
PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Directive[#, "LineColor" -> ColorData[97]@1] & /@  colors,
      {#, f @ #} & /@  {realzero, 0, 1, 2}, 
      LegendMarkers -> markers, Joined -> True];
```

to get

[image]